# Cannot find Log class in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in Android Studio with target for API 22. I have tried to use the `Log` class with the method `d()` but I did not find it. The helper shows only `Log()...`

What am I missing?

Comment: You're probably looking for [Logger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html). Have you searched before asking?

Comment: Did you `import android.util.Log` ?

Comment: i need the log class, well, in the tutorial i'm following the us it

Answer (score 0):

Just import the library `import android.util.Log;`

And just tips: use `alt+space` and `alt+enter` feature from Android Studio

Note:
Alt + Enter = Project quick fix (show intention actions and quick fixes)

Comment: it doesn't work too. i've forgot to mention it... i'm trying to use couchbase, and apparently there's a conflict with the "log" word

Comment: even if couchbase have a library called log, android studio will ask you which one will you use or import. However, if you have to use both Log.d and couchbase log, you should type it manually i think

Comment: android studio says about "log.d" "cannot resolve symbol  d"... what do you mean with "you should type it manually"?